# parseFloat on $(this).val() returns an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ready(function {
    $('.timeViewList input').on("blur", validateHrs);
});

function validateHrs(){
    var e = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

Getting stuck at this next line.

```
    if (e.isNumeric() && (0 < e < 24)) {...}
}
```

It is throwing a type object, because e is an object, and does not recognize the function isNumeric(). As in "Uncaught TypeError: Object 18.37 has no method 'isNumeric'

I understand that parseFloat() is not working on $(this).val(). Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that floats don't have an `isNumeric` function, which is exactly what the error message says.

Try this:

```
if(!isNaN(e) ... )
```

Furthermore, `0 < e < 24` won't work either. You need to write

```
if(!isNaN(e) && 0 < e && e < 24)
```

Comment: Right. Don't need to check if it's numeric, exactly. Just need to make sure parseFloat returned a valid float. Thank you for the quick answer. (It will let me accept in a few minutes.)

Answer (score 0):

[isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) is a method of the jQuery object. [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is a vanilla JavaScript function. You can't expect a standard JavaScript function to return a jQuery object. This one, in particular, returns either a number of `NaN`. Incidentally, [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) allows you to test if your `e` variable is not a number.

*BTW, all decent browsers nowaday (and Internet Explorer) provide a builtin JavaScript console that, among other features, allows you to `console.log()` your variables. There's absolutely no need to guess.*